# Refresh table contents with AJAX using Python's Flask microframework

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to paginate a data table with AJAX. I've created a SQLAlchemy query that takes in user input, and from there I've created a list of dictionaries which hold each result of the query. I need to make my data JSON serializable, and I've tried using [this JavaScript tool](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), but it says that my query object (variable "select" in models.py) is not serializable. I tried working around that and using the list of dicts titled "rows," but each of my queries are too large to be stored in a flask "session" object (as seen in views.py).

I know of SQLAlchemy's paginate function, but I'm unsure of whether or not that would be the best way to implement the pagination feature to my table. I'd like to use AJAX (can you use sqlalchemy's paginate function and AJAX in conjunction?), but I am a beginner with JS and don't know how to accomplish AJAX implementation. Any help?

Here is a breakdown of my code so far. I don't think table schema is necessary to post, but please note that I'm loading existing tables by creating classes and turning autoload to True. There are datetime objects which appear in each query, so maybe that's the reason the query object isn't JSON serializable?

models.py:

```
class Stations(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stations"
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

class Metar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "metar"
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

def loadSession(form):
    clear_mappers()
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(engine, only=['metar', 'stations'])
    stations = Table('stations', metadata, \
                  Column('stationID', Integer, \
                    ForeignKey("metar.stationID"), primary_key=True), \
                    autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)
    mapper(Stations, stations)
    metar = Table('metar', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    mapper(Metar, metar)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    connect = Session()

    queries = []
    #
    # Code not pertinent to question
    # takes user input query params and enters them into query

    time_constraints = []
    #
    # Code not pertinent to question
    # takes user input query params and enters them into query

    # creates sqlalchemy query object
    select = connect.query(Metar.stationID, Metar.ldatetime, Metar.temp, Metar.dew,
                            Metar.wspd, Metar.wdir, Metar.wgust, Metar.vrb,
                            Stations.id, Stations.name, Stations.state).\
                        join(Stations).\
                        filter(or_(*queries), and_(*time_constraints))

    # creates list of dicts containing query response information
    rows = []
    for result in select:
        rows.append(dict(zip(result.keys(), result)))

    return rows, select
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/data_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_post():
    rows, select = loadSession(form=form)
    session['rows'] = rows
    return redirect(url_for('results'))

@app.route('/results', methods=['GET','POST'])
def results():
    rows = session.get('rows', None)
    return render_template('data_display.html', rows=rows)
```

data_display.html

```
<div class="data_display" id="ajax">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ICAO ID</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Station Name</th>
            <th>Local Time</th>
            <th>Temp</th>
            <th>Dew Point</th>
            <th>Wind Speed</th>
            <th>Wind Direction</th>
            <th>Wind Gust</th>
            <th>Variable Wind</th>
        </tr>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row['stationID'] }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('stations', stationID = row['id']) }}">{{ row['id'] }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('state', state = row['state']) }}">{{ row['state'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['name'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['ldatetime'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['temp'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['dew'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['wspd'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['wdir'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['wgust'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row['vrb'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will edit to answer your question (if you feel I havent answered it), but I need to know (cuz its a bit vague) Are you trying to refresh the front end or back end. I don't know how to help you with the back end, but do with the front end.

first, you need to load jquery

```
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then after the div that contains your table, add another java script block

```
<script>
    setInterval(function()
    {
    $('#ajax').load(document.URL +  ' #ajax');
    }, 1000)

</script>
```

In this scenario, I made a script block that only reloads your table div
every 1 second, or 1000 milliseconds.  I made it reload your div by using the div id ('ajax') you provided (thank you for that, it saved so much time). PS, you will not be able to scroll the table, but will have to scroll the entire page, should the table be long. to solve this, you can use iframe, but i dont know if you want to do that (comment below so I can give you the code for that).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. What I'd like to do is reload on the server side. [Here's what my site looks like in the current state.](http://i.imgur.com/SDszBKY.png) My plan is to return ~100 query results on that page, then, once the user scrolls to the bottom of the table, the next 100 rows are loaded. Then, the user scrolls to the NEW bottom of the page, and the next 100 are loaded, and so on. Similar to the Reddit Enhancement Suite's scrolling feature, if you're familiar.

Comment: Oh i see.  Heres a link to a code pen snippet https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH. Hopefully you can build off of this. Its not automatic thought. The user must press a button.